# Effective way to get the route point list using gps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-maps, android-location

I have a method to draw a route on a Google Maps.
This method needs a `List` of `LatitudeLongitude` objects that, as name suggests, contains couples of `double latitude` and `double longitude`.

Now I need to implement a method that fills the route points list, in this way:

the method

```
protected void startFillList(){
  //to do
}
```

start to get coordinate and add these in the list during the movement,

the method

```
protected List<LatitudeLongitude> stopFillList(){
  //to do
}
```

stop to get new coordinates and returns the result list

How could I do this?

If I use a while that invokes continuously (until stop condition reached)

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

to fill the list, the app hangs brutally.

Comment: Use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). The response should contain points which you can use to fill your list.

Comment: @Andy could you give me more details or a sample? I have given a look to the link but I haven't understood how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can try this way:

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> CoordsList = new ArrayList<>();
private static boolean addCoords = false;


protected void startFillList(){
   addCoords = true;
}

protected ArrayList<LatLng> stopFillList(){
   addCoords = false;
   return CoordsList; 
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object and add to list
    currentCoods = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //check condition if add coordinates
    if(addCoords)
        CoordsList.add(currentCoods);

}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: @AndreaF, is this answer helping your issue?

Comment: @AndreaF, are you going to accept my solution, or you have got better solution? I suppose my solution is simple and effective, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
     GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
     com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  
{

LocationManager locationManager;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

List<LatitudeLongitude> myPositions=new List<LatitudeLongitude>();
//Update Position after 2 minutes
private static final int UPDATE_POS_AFTER_MILLIS=120000;
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    startFillList()

}

protected void startFillList(){
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() 
{
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
        if(googleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if(currentLocation!=null)
            {
                LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(
                    (float) currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    (float) currentLocation.getLongitude());
                myPositions.add(currentLatLng);
                //This is for periodically request
                createLocationRequest();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Notify User GPS is disabled
    }
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_POS_AFTER_MILLIS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}
//After 2 Minutes this method will be called
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(
                    (float) currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    (float) currentLocation.getLongitude());
    myPositions.add(currentLatLng);
}

protected List<LatitudeLongitude> stopFillList(){
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, this);
    return myPositions;
}

}
```

Don't forget to implements all interface methods